# How to disable fast application switching (multitasking) on iOS 4?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, ios4

In iOS 4, when a user presses the Home button, the running app will save the current state and go to background. However I'm developing an app and I don't want it to go to the background. I want it to kill itself, just like in iOS 3 and before. How can I do it? Thanks.

Answer (score 31, accepted):

See "[Opting Out of Background Execution](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/iPhone/Conceptual/iPhoneOSProgrammingGuide/ManagingYourApplicationsFlow/ManagingYourApplicationsFlow.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40007072-CH4-SW5)" in the [iOS Application Programming Guide](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/iPhone/Conceptual/iPhoneOSProgrammingGuide/Introduction/Introduction.html%23//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40007072-CH1-SW1):

> "...you can explicitly opt out of the
>   background execution model by adding
>   the **UIApplicationExitsOnSuspend** key to
>   your application’s **Info.plist** file and
>   setting its value to **YES**."

Comment: Thanks for your lightning fast answer. It really helps a lot!

Comment: Sure. However StackOverflow tells me that I can't accept your answer in less than 10 minutes. You're just too fast =)

Comment: [ corny ] That's how I roll, son! [ /corny ]

Comment: "UIApplicationExitsOnSuspend" is now: "Application does not run in background mode". I also had do define the launch image in the info.plist else it went black.

Comment: Any suggestion on how to implement that as an option for the user? Since Info.plist is readonly
I've tried putting an `exit(0);` on `applicationWillResignActive`, But besides being against Apple's rules, it gives bad UX.

Comment: I suggest posting a new question about this. Make sure to explain why you feel the need to do this, since you could just opt not to execute stuff in the background in your app.