# How do I make it so that every time my app is opened, it goes to the 'main menu'?

Tags: ios4

right now, every time my iphone app is opened in the simulator, it goes to the window that was last opened. how do i make it so that it goes to the 'main menu' every time the app is opened?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can just opt out of fast app switching: [How to disable fast application switching (multitasking) on iOS 4?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4138368/how-to-disable-fast-application-switching-multitasking-on-ios-4)

This will force your app to always launch fresh each time.