# How to ensure iOS app doesn't remain suspended in the background indefinitely?

Tags: ios, objective-c, ipad

Our iOS app retrieves new app data every time it is freshly started i.e. not resumed from the background. App data is updated periodically every couple of months via web services so this is generally fine.

However, there may be edge cases where the user's iOS device - iPad, specifically - may keep the app suspended in the background for an extended period of time - potentially indefinitely.

Is it possible to mitigate this edge case by telling iOS "please release this app if it has been suspended for more than a few hours"?

Comment: Why does your app need to be restarted to refresh its data? That's simply a bad design. Why not check for new data when the app starts or returns to the foreground and update the data as needed. A restart should not be required if the app is written properly.

Comment: File a bug with Apple: Application operations should be killed after 10 minutes by the OS.

Comment: The app checks for new data when each time it starts fresh.  The trouble is edge cases where the App can remain in a suspended state indefinitely.

Comment: You can disable multitasking completely? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4138368/how-to-disable-fast-application-switching-multitasking-on-ios-4

Comment: Disabling multitasking completely is a good start, but not ideal since the app may go to the background when the user clicks a link that opens a browser or apple maps.

Comment: @Kevin Why is sitting in the background for a long time a problem for your app? Is it because new data may be available and since the app isn't starting fresh, your app isn't smart enough to check for the new data? What about if the user just happens to switch to another app seconds before new data becomes available and then the user returns the app 10 minutes later. That's not long but the app still won't see the data. You need to fix the app to work properly.

Comment: @rmaddy, the problem is in edge cases where the app, in theory, can remain suspended - in memory - indefinitely.  App data gets refreshed approx. every three months.  We want a simple solution to handle this edge case.  I doubt a solution exists, but I want to find out for sure via the community...

Comment: @Kevin It's not just that edge case you need to deal with. The example I gave in my previous comment is an issue too. The solution is simple - you need to fix your app to check for data updates when the app returns to the foreground in addition to app startup.

Comment: @rmaddy, I understand these cases - this data is not time sensitive and it is fine for it to passively update even a week late.  A high percentage of the time the app will naturally exit, whether due to iOS releasing memory or a reset of the device itself, within several days which is totally acceptable.  If there was a simple way to tell a set of view controllers to reload from scratch if the app was in the backgorund for a period of days, that would be another acceptable - if not elegant - solution

Answer (score 3):

The issue you describe is due to poor app design or a poor understanding of app architecture. If you need to refresh app data whenever the app becomes active you can simply call your update function off of the [UIApplicationDelegate](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UIApplicationDelegate_Protocol/Reference/Reference.html) event (or register for a notification), specifically:

> applicationDidBecomeActive:
>
> Tells the delegate that the application has become active.
>   - (void)applicationDidBecomeActive:(UIApplication *)application Parameters
>
> application
>
> ```
> The singleton application instance.
> ```
>
> Discussion
>
> This method is called to let your application know that it moved from
>   the inactive to active state. This can occur because your application
>   was launched by the user or the system. Applications can also return
>   to the active state if the user chooses to ignore an interruption
>   (such as an incoming phone call or SMS message) that sent the
>   application temporarily to the inactive state.
>
> You should use this method to restart any tasks that were paused (or
>   not yet started) while the application was inactive. For example, you
>   could use it to restart timers or throttle up OpenGL ES frame rates.
>   If your application was previously in the background, you could also
>   use it to refresh your application’s user interface.
>
> After calling this method, the application also posts a
>   UIApplicationDidBecomeActiveNotification notification to give
>   interested objects a chance to respond to the transition. Availability

Comment: The app design is meant to fit into a tight budget.  Given resources we could of course handle applicationDidBecomeActive, implement web service features to check for new data, release old data in the app, and rebuild UI's for active view controllers based on this new data.

Comment: Huh? How do you get your data in the first place? If it is hard coded in the app then killing it when it enters the background is not going to help. If it calls out to retrieve new data then you only have to make the same call from `applicationDidBecomeActive`.

Comment: Data comes from web services which are accessed during app startup while a nice little intro movie plays.  The issue is not getting the new data... it's reloading all the view controllers with that new data in a seamless way.

Comment: imo - the way you are defining the problem is creating the problem. Put up an activity indicator or custom graphic while updating the data. If you want to get fancy then store version numbers or dates for the data to determine if the UI needs refreshing.

Comment: It'd be great if we could release all our tabs / view controllers and recreate them from scratch if the user resumes after an extended idle period.  Maybe that was the right question to ask.  We just need a quick and easy solution at this point, elegance for this edge case is not a priority.

Answer (score 0):

When the app is suspended it shouldn't be refreshing. Per Apple's documentation, unless your app has registered for one of the specific background processes, the app is essentially frozen until it resumes. There shouldn't be any network calls made.

However, if you DO want to kill the app once it's been suspended for too long, you could implement a hack that registers a background timer for 10 minutes, then after 10 minutes call some garbage code that you know will crash. Problem solved :)

Comment: LOL doubt that makes it past the App Store approval nazis but it's a thought.