# Application crashing when reopen from the background in iphone 6

Tags: ios, swift, iphone-6

I have one issue which is related to my iphone6. When i install the app and run the app for first time it is working fine. Once the app is entered into background mode and again i want to reopen the app, the application suddenly crashed without calling any application delegate methods and killed from background. Again tap on the app icon, it is launched from starting on words. It is happening only on my iphone6 device. I tested same scenario with another iphone6 device it is working perfectly. What should i do resolve this problem.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Take a look at the crashlogs from your device, they should tell you what the problem is.

Comment: Share the crash log. And also your App delegate methods regarding mode switching.

Comment: And a dummy question: is somehow multitasking disabled in your Info.plist (see [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4138368/how-to-disable-fast-application-switching-multitasking-on-ios-4) for more details)?

Comment: But app is working fine in all devices that what i have, only this problem occurs in my iphone6 device other than this everything working fine. Event i want to try to print the logs with application delegate methods, even one single method is not calling at that time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally, i found the problem where it was happening. Problem is with CoreTelephony framework. Initially, i am checking for network signal whether it is 2G or 3G etc.. This framework sometimes returns null value through notification.

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar issue once: do you have a third-party framework in your project? If so, you need to include it in your binary so your app can run.

Go to your project, 
`Build Phases > Link Binary with Libraries`
and add your framework. Also, go to `Build Phases > Embed Frameworks` and add the framework there too.

Comment: Thanks Gabriel Jones, yes i added frameworks through pod file and that was also included in Buiild phases but still problem is exist. Even i updated my device OS too.

Comment: Did you rebuild your project first @nari